# I Wanted to know if we can use Katalon for Cucumber BDD frame work but, with Java and not Groovy scripts?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, katalon

We are using [Katalon](https://www.katalon.com/), but I always wanted to use Cucumber BDD framework.

I have he seen that Katalon 5.7 started incorporating Cucumber BDD framework. 
But, I am not sure how to use it for Java as it only accepts Groovy scripts?

Can you please let me know if it can accept Java code?

Comment: Yes, In Katalon studio we can use java code

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation BDD steps can also be implemented in Java:

> Step Definitions can be written in any Cucumber-supported programming
>   languages including Groovy and **Java**.
>
> https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/step-definitions.html